# Using command line arguments to launch url in system web browser

Tags: python, argument-passing

I would like to execute a script with parameters, these parameters must be send into the URL.

So, the main problem, is how to do this task ?

That's my test script to do this, I used sys.argv ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

print "The name is :", sys.argv[0]
print "number of arguments :", len(sys.argv)
print "arguments are :", str(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? If you are asking for a framework for argument parsing, take a look at the argparse or the optparse module of python.

Comment: @flammi88: Of course ... So, I want to execute a script with parameters like this script.py param1 param2 param3. These parameters must be filled by the user and then when you execute this command script.py param1 param2 param3 , it opens a web page in your webbrowser ( of course this step is finished ). that's clear now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (Python 3 code):

```
import webbrowser
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Accept URL parameters on the command line.')
parser.add_argument('UserID', metavar='UID', type=str, nargs=1,
                   help='The User ID')
parser.add_argument('UserName', metavar='UName', type=str, nargs=1,
                    help = 'The User Name')

args = parser.parse_args()
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/%s/%s' % (args.UserID[0], args.UserName[0])
print(url)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

It sounds like you want non-optional command line arguments - so [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) seems the way to go, see the documentation for options and parameters etc.

Comment: Yes, it's something like this, just my URL is different ( it's normal :) ), and I use python 2.7.

Comment: Just a note: The [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) package is also available as python 2.7 package

Comment: @flammi88: Yes, and I use webbrowser into one of my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the script can be accessed via the sys.argv array. For example:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
   print "http://www.google.de?q=%s&%s" % (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
else:
   print "Usage: <Explain params here>"
```

Every argument that is seperated with a space in the command-line can be accessed via the index in the sys.argv array.

Is this that you were looking for?

EDIT:

If you have a more complex use case where you need a more complex argmument parser, you can use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module of python.

Comment: Actually, yes that's a good idea, but I need to open the webbrowser ( I have already my script who does that ). in your example, you write to standard output (the terminal)... you understand ?

Comment: Is your code to open the webbrowser encapsulated in a function? If yes then simply call the function were I printed the result to sysout...

Comment: I have info.py wherein I open an other script like this : webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8000/cgi/recup_hello_get.py'), but 
parameters that are specified with the script must be displayed in http://localhost:8000/cgi/recup_hello_get.py ( so I have 3 parameters : the name of the modul, the version of the modul and path installation of the modul).